# Simple algorithm to fit a one-dimensional 4 point cubic curve to a given dataset

Tags: algorithms, regression, cubics

**I want to fit a basic cubic curve to a given data set of multiple points.**

It's a fairly simple fitting and I'm looking for an "easy" or "reduced" algorithm to help me do that.

I'm dealing with an **"easing curve"** here - it's always **starting with 0,0** and **ending with 1,1**.

> [Some curve like this one](https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/684fd5ea-08c4-433c-8046-6698181fd6c4/03-bezier-curve-ease-in-out.jpg).
>
> --> Here you can also see the s[pecial kind of cubic bezier curve I'm talking about](http://cubic-bezier.com/#1,0,0,1)

In between it **may reach values over 1 or below 0** but it will always start and end like this.

Now I want to fit such a dataset with a 4 point cubic bezier curve.
P0 and P3 being (0|0) and (1|1).

All I need to know is P1 and P2, so that the resulting cubic curve is as close to the given data set as possible.

p.E. my dataset looks like this:

`PX | 0.00 | 0.08 | 0.17 | 0.25 | 0.33 | 0.42 | 0.50 | 0.58 ... 0.92 | 1.00 |`

`PY | 0.00 | 0.01 | 0.03 | 0.07 | 0.15 | 0.29 | 0.48 | 0.69 ... 0.99 | 1.00 |`

And my desired output something like

P0 ( 0 | 0 )

P1 ( 0.625 | 0 )

P2 ( 0.39 | 1 )

P3 ( 1 | 1 ).

Can you help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to define a function $f(PX,P1,P2)$ which is the calculated value of $PY$ based on the input.  Then add up the squares of the errors $(PY-f(PX,P1,P2))^2$ over all the points.  Use a function minimizer to find the values of P1 and P2.  If $f$ is linearly dependent on P1 and P2 you can use a linear least squares method, otherwise you need a multidimensional minimizer.  Any numerical analysis text will have a discussion.  You can also use Excel and its goal seek to do the minimization.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! But what kind of function would f(PX,P1,P2) be? And also, PX would be one dimensional while P1 and P2 are two-dimensional values, how do I solve these kind of functions then?

Comment: The function should be in one of the links.  If P1 and P2 are two dimensional that just means your function has four parameters. We could call the two associated with P1 as P1x,P1y.  You then have some expression like $f(PX,P1,P2)=P1y(P1x-0)^2+P2y(P2x-1)^2$, which I just made up to look something like a Bezier curve.  It represents the predicted value of PY for a given PX based on your parameters.

Comment: Ok - but I still can't get it to the end. For a cubic bezier i found this [article](http://mrcslws.com/blocks/2015/02/26/using-bezier-curves-as-easing-functions.html) which describes the formula of x and y equally as $x(t)=3*P1x(1-t)^2*t+3*P2x*(1-t)*t^2+t^3)$ if $P0=(0,0)$ and $P1=(1,1)$.

But now I have a problem. I can make 4 euqations to be solved for 4 variables ($P1x;P1y,P2x,P2y$) but still there is the $t$ in every equation I need to know as well. But how? 5 Variables, 5 Equations? How can I find another equation to solve the riddle? :)

Comment: I think $t$ is just $PX$ here.  It is the fractional distance from one endpoint to the next.  Your $P1y$ and $P2y$ are not in the equation at all.

Comment: Ah ok - sure $t=PX$! But what do you mean with y is not in the equation? Isn’t then $Py(Px ) = 3*P1y*(1-Px)^2*Px+3*P2y*(1-Px)*Px^2+Px ^3$

Comment: I see, that is what you meant by symmetric.  Now, as you say, you can just pick two points and solve four equations in four unknowns.  That will make the curve go exactly through those two points and ignore the other two.  Summing the squared error will consider all the points and pick the parameters that give the best fit.  Either will work, you need to decide which you want.